# Is there any side-effect of "cryptography==2.4.2" installation because of "CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2" error?

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-cryptography

With docker-compose -f  up -d have observed following error :
`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/__init__.py:39: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography, and will be removed in a future release.`

As a workaround have tried

```
pip install cryptography==2.4.2
```

But will there be any side-effect of this installation or will there be any functionality which will not work?

Comment: Why are you still using Python 2?

Comment: I'm seeing this error while starting container with docker-compose, can you suggest where in docker-compose can i switch to python 3 ?

Comment: In the *compose* file you likely can't, you need to update the image it's starting.

Answer (score 0):

this warning was added in [cryptography 3.0](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst#30---2020-07-20):

> Deprecated support for Python 2. At the time there is no time table for actually dropping support, however we strongly encourage all users to upgrade their Python, as Python 2 no longer receives support from the Python core team.

so no side effect for now

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a lot of features added between cryptography 2.4 and 3.0. They're all documented here: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/changelog/. If you are using binary wheels from PyPI then you'll also be missing many security fixes to OpenSSL.